# Grouping bootstrap column with a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap, I need to keep the proportion of the following columns, yet I need to group 2 columns with a div so that I can modify the background.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"></div>
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="grey">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

But it changes the proportion, as it is considering grey div as 18 grid.

Comment: do you mean you want all 3 columns to be the same width? or the first one as half the width, and the next 2 as 1/4 each?

Comment: 3 columns of same width.

Answer (score 0):

My personal advise will be this. Though I'm really certain of what your goal is. Since bootstrap has an 12 wide grid your col-xs-6 will put 2 columns beside each other and the next one below.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 grey"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 grey"></div>
```

If you really looking for grouping I should consider this approach:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="grey col-md-9">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8"></div>
</div>
```

But that will not correspond when he enters xs. Since it is not clear to me what you want with that size.

Answer (score 0):

`col-*-4` will give you 3 columns of equal width (spanning 4 cols each). No need to group them to modify their background color. Just apply the same class with background color defined in your css:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 grey">Col 2</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 grey">Col 3</div>
```

css

```
.grey{backround:grey;}
```

**Demo: http://www.bootply.com/E78M9vm9Uk**